# Deploy azure subscription using azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, subscription, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to deploy a new azure subscription into a management group using azure devops pipeline.
I have created a management group and a service principle , I assign the contributor role on the mgm group to the sp and then created a new service connection on the management group scope.
My problem is that I can not find this service connection in my pipeline task.
How can I use this service connection in my pipeline to deploy subscription?

[image: Edit service connection dialog]

Comment: Have you tried the following steps?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could add the "[ARM Template deployment](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3)" task in the azure pipeline to deploy a new azure subscription into a management group.

In classic pipeline:

[image: ARM Template deployment]

For more information about the ARM of the mangement group, you could refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-management-group?tabs=azure-cli#scope-to-subscription).